# What access to Google Cloud Storage is required to execute jobs on the Google Cloud Dataflow Service?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

The answer below includes responses to the following common questions.

- Why is Cloud Storage required to execute jobs on the Dataflow
  Service?
- Can I execute jobs with read-only access to Cloud Storage?

Comment: Well, where were you *expecting* to keep the data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every Dataflow job uses Cloud Storage for two purposes:

1. The *staging location* is where the Dataflow SDK uploads the jars necessary to execute the job. The Dataflow Service requires **read** access to the staging location.

The SDK requires **write** access to staging in order to upload the jars that contain the job code. However, in the case that all jars are already staged in the current form, the SDK can execute jobs using **read-only** access.

Note that staged files persist across jobs.

2. The *temp location* is used by the Dataflow Service for temporary storage during job execution. The service requires **write** access to the temporary location.

Temporary storage is deleted on job success.

Both **staging location** and **temp location** are controlled using [DataflowPipelineOptions](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.26.0/org/apache/beam/runners/dataflow/options/DataflowPipelineOptions.html). Note that if only one of these two locations is specified then Dataflow will use the same path for both.

Now, assuming that you have previously uploaded all jars to the staging location, a user with read-only access to the staging location should be able to execute a job as long as she specifies a separate, writable temp location. The following example command would run WordCount:

```
java -cp your_bundled_jar com.google.cloud.dataflow.examples.WordCount 
    --project=PROJECT --runner=BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner
    --stagingLocation=gs://READONLY-BUCKET/staging
    --tempLocation=gs:/WRITABLE-BUCKET/temp
    --output=gs://WRITABLE-BUCKET/output
```